# How to use material2 toolbar, button and angular-cli router

Tags: angular, typescript1.8, angular-cli, angular-material2

I have the following files:

### .html

```
<nav>
  <md-toolbar color = "primary">
    <a [routerLink] = "['new-patient']">New Patient</a>

    <button md-icon-button
            color = "accent">
      <md-icon class = "material-icons md-24">person_add</md-icon>
    </button>
  </md-toolbar>
</nav>
```

### .ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router';
import { MdToolbar } from '@angular2-material/toolbar';
import { MdIcon, MdIconRegistry } from '@angular2-material/icon';
import { MdButton } from '@angular2-material/button';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'epimss-toolbar',
  templateUrl: 'toolbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['toolbar.component.css'],
  providers: [MdIconRegistry],
 directives: [MdButton, MdIcon, MdToolbar, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
})
export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

My router actually works with the above code.

However, I am trying the

```
<a [routerLink] = "['new-patient']">New Patient</a>
```

to be a route that is activated when the

```
<button md-icon-button
        color = "accent">
  <md-icon class = "material-icons md-24">person_add</md-icon>
</button>
```

is clicked.

I have tried the following but it does not work.

```
<button md-icon-button
        color = "accent"
        [routerLink] = "['new-patient']">
  <md-icon class = "material-icons md-24">person_add</md-icon>
</button>
```

Appreciate any help given please, and thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is because the new Router doesn't accept `[routerLink]` on `<button>` elements, only `<a>` tags.

But you're in luck, Material lets you do the icon on `<a>` and `<button>`

[Material Docs on md-button](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/components/button)

So try this:

```
<a md-icon-button
        [routerLink] = "['new-patient']"
        color = "accent">
  <md-icon class = "material-icons md-24">person_add</md-icon>
</a>
```